# Wordpress Very Slow Query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
              , tt.* 
           FROM wp_terms t  
           JOIN wp_termmeta 
             ON t.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id 
           JOIN wp_termmeta mt1 
             ON t.term_id = mt1.term_id 
           JOIN wp_termmeta mt2 
             ON t.term_id = mt2.term_id 
           JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
             ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
          WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('episodes') 
            AND wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'episode_number'  
            AND mt1.meta_key = 'tr_id_post' 
            AND mt1.meta_value = '7547' 
            AND mt2.meta_key = 'season_number' 
            AND mt2.meta_value = '2' 
          ORDER 
             BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC;
```

I don't know how to make it faster, it takes like 1.2 sec to execute, my website loads very hard because of it.

Comment: Have you checked with `EXPLAIN` yet? Why are you doing `wp_termmeta.meta_value+0` with computation?

Comment: @tadman Seems reasonable to me

Comment: Hello, sorry i don't know very much sql. Thats why i need help. With explain i got this: https://i.imgur.com/QCr3wjF.png

Comment: It's not expected that you know everything. That's why they have [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html).

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Any time you see "using filesort" you've got problems. The problem is usually a missing index. Do you really need to join the same table three times?

Comment: @tadman  Knowing wordpress it's probably necessary to join that `termmeta` table twice. It's like an EAV schema. I'm guessing indexing is the issue here.

Comment: @JNevill Looks like it, but the first JOIN seems redundant. It's never used.

Comment: The index needed is on meta_value, but i get this: 
ALTER TABLE `wp_termmeta` ADD INDEX(`meta_value`);
MySQL said: Documentation

#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'meta_value' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Yes, a missing _composite_ index; see the link in my Answer.  Double JOIN, yes; EAV sucks.  Don't bother indexing `value`; do `(term_id, meta_key)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the table?  Check to see if a plugin is flooding that table with junk that it fails to clear out.

The "meta" tables have an inefficient schema.  This explains what to do to improve the performance of them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta